# Sqlserver CTE how to get first non null value

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to use the following query to get a user with his detail and any of his manager or manager's manager id who got a record in UserTag table.

I have got the partial result, but not sure how to get the first non null value. I have show my expected result below.

```
With Managers AS 
( 
--initialization 
SELECT Id, Email, ManagerID, NULL as UserID
FROM dbo.[User] 
WHERE email='user@test.com'
UNION ALL 
--recursive execution 
SELECT u.Id, u.Email, u.ManagerID, tb2.UserID
FROM dbo.[User] u 
    INNER JOIN Managers m ON m.ManagerID = u.ID
    OUTER apply (select userid from UserTag where userid = m.ManagerID and (TagID=9 or TagName = 'test')) tb2
) 
SELECT * FROM Managers
```

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Sample data and expected result:

```
User table
=========

Id      Email           ManagerID
---     -----           ---------
11813   userA@test.com  1251
1251    userB@test.com  302
302     userC@test.com  1221
1221    userD@test.com  358
358     userE@test.com  988
988     userE@test.com  NULL

100     userA1@test.com 101
101     userB1@test.com 102
102     userC1@test.com 103
103     userD1@test.com 104
104     userF1@test.com NULL

User Tag

Id  UserId      TagId       TagName
1   1221        9           test
2   104         9           test


Expected result
==============

UserId  Email               TagManagerId
------  -----               ------------
11813   userA@test.com      1221
1251    userB@test.com      1221
302     userC@test.com      1221
```

Brief description:
I have all users in User table. This is a self referencing table.
I want to get all users whose immediate manager or manager's manager or any manager in his/hierarchy got a record in UserTag table with tagid=9 or tagname='test' as shown here.

Schema *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b334e9c773bbb6686b6b3f1e9fe6873)*

Comment: As was mentioned in your last question, **consumable** sample data, and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, i have update the query with expected result

Comment: Hi @Larnu, i have added more details with sample data and expected result.

Comment: I must admit, I really don't follow the logic here; can you elaborate.

Comment: When you say 'first', what do you mean? Data sets in SQL are explicitly un-ordered sets, unless you apply an ORDER BY. So, in your case, what would define the order?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `Brief description`, I believe that this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

- There are solutions to the real need that don't include `get first non null value`.

What I believe you really need to do is find all the managers that are `tagid=9 or tagname='test'` and then recursively find all their subordinates.  *(Run the recursion in the opposite direction to your example query.)*

The only complexity I can think of is that such a manager may have a subordinate that also meets those criteria, so I included a condition to avoid recursing them more than once.

```
WITH
  test9_managed_users AS
(
  SELECT
    u.*,
    u.managerid   AS closest_test9_manager_id,
    0             AS depth
  FROM
    [user]    AS u
  INNER JOIN
    UserTag   AS t
      ON  t.userid = u.managerid
      AND (t.TagID=9 or TagName = 'test')
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    u.*,
    m.closest_test9_manager_id,
    m.depth+1
  FROM
    test9_managed_users   AS m
  INNER JOIN
    [user]                AS u
      ON u.managerid = m.id
  WHERE
    -- If a user is themselves a 'test9_manager', don't recurse their children
    -- > They would already have been included in the Anchor part of the CTE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
        FROM UserTag  AS t
       WHERE t.userid = m.id
         AND (t.TagID=9 or TagName = 'test')
    )
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  test9_managed_users
ORDER BY
  email
```

Demo with my own test data:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e901a6f7db97362bb27ebacb1d4331c

Demo with your test data:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1ab3625ba797d8fc13c49872d1cd5872